# What do I do with Bronze Alloy?

Tags: junk-jack-x

What do I do with Bronze Alloy in Junk Jack X? I made some but what can I do with it?

Answer (score 2):

I personally have never heard of this game before, but after a quick search I found a sort of resource guide for the game.

http://confessor.org/projects/junkjackx.php?Item=61

Judging from this page, it would appear you use the Bronze Alloy to create Bronze Ingot. To find how to create this, just go to the bottom of the page as shown below.

[image]

From there you can find what the ingots are used for.